# ifconfig + FAILED from ifconfig on solaris machines

Tags: networking, solaris, ethernet

please advice - what the meaning of FAILED word from ifconfig command

1. Dose its mean that network from NIC isn't stable until this moment ?
2. Not clearly if ifconfig read network status each some mili seconds?, I mean if network is stable so ifconfig should return the FAILED status to OK ?

yael

```
 ifconfig -a

   lo0: flags=2001000849<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST,IPv4,VIRTUAL> mtu 8232 index 1
       inet 127.0.0.1 netmask ff000000 
    e1000g0: flags=19000802<BROADCAST,MULTICAST,IPv4,NOFAILOVER,FAILED> mtu 0 index 2
         inet 0.0.0.0 netmask 0 
         groupname Mgmt_ipmp
         ether 0:21:28:58:ff:6 
    e1000g1: flags=11000803<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,IPv4,FAILED> mtu 1500 index 3
          inet 0.0.0.0 netmask ff000000 broadcast 0.255.255.255
          groupname Mgmt_ipmp
          ether 0:21:28:58:ff:7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`man ifconfig`

section called "INTERFACE FLAGS"

```
 FAILED

     The  interface  has  failed.  New  addresses  cannot  be
     created  on this interface. If this interface is part of
     an IP network multipathing group, a failover will  occur
     to another interface in the group, if possible
```

Sometimes IPMP notices a problem with an interface and marks it as FAILED (this means that the test has failed, not that there is a hardware problem). This is because either be "the link is down" or "the ping test failed" (assuming you have test addresses).